# Firestore security rule not working

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have the following rule in my Firestore

```
service cloud.firestore {
      match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /users/{userId}/{documents=**} {
          // Only the authenticated user who authored the document can read or write
          allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId;
          allow write;
        }
      }
    }
```

which doesn't seem to work and i am using Rest API to get the data 
For authentication I call:
https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=[API_KEY]

Once authenticated we get the idToken and pass as Authorization header for  the next URL
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects//databases/(default)/documents/users

The users collection has the id as the document name and the value is just a bunch of dummy keys.

When I run the client the error I get is

{u'status': u'PERMISSION_DENIED', u'message': u'Missing or insufficient permissions.', u'code': 403}

If i hardcode the value of the userid it works. So the value returned in {userid} does not seem to match the UID for some reason.

Can someone please help decode why this is happening?

Thanks
Rams

Answer (score 1):

you don't need the document=** selector

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // dissallow all access
    match /{documents=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }

    // Make sure the uid of the requesting user matches name of the user
    // document. The wildcard expression {userId} makes the userId variable
    // available in rules.
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions

Comment: Thanks for the response i have tried your solution with adding 'if' before false and i get the same result of PERMISSION_DENIED.

Comment: Lets look at the simple solutions first then. Are you testing in the console? If so make sure you are passing an authorized user id.
Is your auth id the userId at that node? If not, then you are correctly getting permission_denied